# Is it possible to see what's registered with OWIN's IAppBuilder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, owin

I have a solution which makes use of many class libraries (optional plugins). It is actually very similar in design to nopCommerce. Anyway, I have the following interface:

```
public interface IOwinStartupConfiguration
{
    void Configuration(IAppBuilder app);
}
```

Obviously what happens is that in my `Startup` class in the web project, I get a list of all registered `IOwinStartupConfiguration` instances in all plugins and then proceed to iterate over each one.

So far I only have one plugin using this, but that may change later. The thing I'm worried about is the possibility of more than 1 plugin calling something like:

`app.MapSignalR();`

Acccording to this page:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting

doing so would cause an error like

**"A route named 'signalr.hubs' is already in the route collection"**

Is it possible to see what's in the OWIN pipeline?

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
if (!app.IsSignalRMapped)
{
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

or

```
if (!app.HasMappedService("SignalR"))
{
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Obviously I cannot find any such thing on the `IAppBuilder` interface. So what can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon `MapWhen()`, but it seemed a bit pointless. I was going to try something like this:

```
app.MapWhen(x => !existingConfigurations.Contains("SignalR"), x => app.MapSignalR());
```

where `existingConfigurations` is a new `ICollection<string>` passed in the modified method:

```
void Configuration(IAppBuilder app, ICollection<string> existingConfigurations)
```

However, I found it made more sense to simply do this:

```
if (!existingConfigurations.Contains("SignalR"))
{
    app.MapSignalR();
    existingConfigurations.Add("SignalR");
}
```

It's not a perfect solution, since someone could misspell "SignalR", for example. But since there's no `IsSignalRMapped()` method, it will have to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but this might work:

```
var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MySignalRHub>();

if (hub == null) 
{
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```